# Sum values from relationships list in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, sum, cypher, relationship

I have a problem trying to capture the sum of a list from a captured path.

I have been successful in fetching data from the **path** and are getting a result like this:

```
relationships(path)
```

Result:

```
[{"amount":1},{"amount":2},{"amount":3}]
```

I can also fetch the actual values by using this:

```
[node in relationships(path) | coalesce(node.amount)] as nodes.
```

Result:

```
[1,2,3]
```

What I would like was to be able to produce a simple sum of the values in this list. In the example above I would like the result "6".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [REDUCE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/list/#functions-reduce)

`return reduce(total = 0, r IN relationships(p) | total + r.amount) AS total`

Comment: It seemed to be a perfect solution but this was the total of the values in the path not the sum. It was a bad example by me. I wanted 1*2*3=6 not 1+2+3=6.

I did try to change the plus for * in the statement but that only braught 0 values.

Comment: Found the solution. I just needed to set total=1 to start with before multiplying. Thank you for great help Luanne!